# CMAKE: a custom target to install at different location

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am porting our product from using Makefiles to CMAKE.
With Makefile we have 'install' target to move stuff to some location on user's machine and 'deploy' - to some fixed location on a server. I don't want to run 'cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...' to reconfigure each time I need to switch a destination and prefer to minimize extra typing on a command line. Therefore, in my CMakeLists, I have

```
 set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../_install)
```

Now, I am trying to use 'add_custom_target' but not sure how to do this correctly:

```
add_custom_target(DEPLOY
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build . --target install --install ${SITE}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)

set(SITE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/_deploy"
    CACHE PATH "Alternate install prefix for 'deploy'")

add_executable(main main.cpp)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS main)

add_custom_target(
  deploy
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
          --install "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
          --config  "$<CONFIG>"
          --prefix  "${SITE}"
)
```

Which reduces to

```
cmake --build /path/to/build --config ... --target deploy
```

Be warned that none of this will work if your install rules store the value of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`. You have to be careful to use relative paths only. If you do make this mistake, you'll have no choice but to fix your code or reconfigure.

Comment: Nope. add_custom_command did not work. 'deploy' installs at default location. Even if I do not modify CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX. Am I missing something?

Comment: @def - Where did I say `add_custom_command`? I wrote `add_custom_target`.

Comment: sure, add_custom_target, sorry. And I'm 'dying' to have it as a convenient way to trigger this from Visual Studio.

Comment: @def - I updated my answer with a full example you can try for yourself.

Comment: @def - given that your question wrote "porting [...] from using Makefiles", I assumed you would be working primarily at the command line, sorry.

Comment: ours is a multiplatform one, including Windows as well

Comment: You had a Makefile that worked on both Windows and Unix? No wonder you're porting to CMake! ;)

Comment: Made it working! Thanks. My mistake was I end up with absolute path for destination for install statement. That's why --prefix didn't work.

Comment: @def - Happy to help! :)